# No Exception named in log of crash

Tags: android

My app crashed while doing an update, but it didn't tell me what the exception was there's just a blank where it would normally print the exception, here's the logcat:

```
02-06 04:00:21.306 E/AndroidRuntime( 5582):     at com.myapp.services.MonthUpdateService.processIntent(MonthUpdateService.java:167)
02-06 04:00:21.306 E/AndroidRuntime( 5582):     at com.myapp.services.UpdateService.onHandleIntent(UpdateService.java:215)
02-06 04:00:21.353 I/ActivityManager(17864): Process com.myapp (pid 5582) has died.
02-06 04:00:21.353 W/ActivityManager(17864): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp/.services.MonthUpdateService in 42414ms
02-06 04:05:29.853 I/ActivityManager(17864): Start proc com.myapp for service com.myapp/.services.MonthUpdateService: pid=5718 uid=10090 gids={3003, 1028}
02-06 04:05:46.009 E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):     at com.myapp.services.MonthUpdateService.processIntent(MonthUpdateService.java:167)
02-06 04:05:46.009 E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):     at com.myapp.services.UpdateService.onHandleIntent(UpdateService.java:215)
02-06 04:05:46.032 I/ActivityManager(17864): Process com.myapp (pid 5718) has died.
02-06 04:05:46.032 W/ActivityManager(17864): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{42be7440 com.myapp/.services.MonthUpdateService}
```

The code where it crashed:

```
catch( IOException e )
{
    //TODO Schedule a retry for IO Exception.
    Log.w( TAG,  e.getMessage() ); // LINE 167
}
```

I guess it must be a `NullPointerException` but that makes no sense as `e` can't be null if it gets to that line, right?  The more important question, though, is why is the exception not printed in the log?

Comment: that's the `getMessage()` from a NullPointerException. you'd see more stuff if you followed the Log line with `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: But a NullPointerException shouldn't be caught here, it should just crash the app (and show up in the log).  It shouldn't be printing the NullPointerException message here.

Comment: yeah, i just realized that. i get NPE's all the time and am used to seeing <nothing>. the `e.printStackTrace()` will show you more information. try it!

Comment: @Ralgha  Try it using e.printStackTrace(); David M is saying right..

Comment: I determined that `getMessage` on the IOException is returning null, which causes the NullPointerException in the Log.w method, so I can fix that.  I'm not understanding what you're telling me to do `e.printStackTrace()` on though, I don't care about the IOException's trace, I want the NullPointerException's trace.  Normally when I get one of those it prints the trace without me having to catch it.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` should go on the next line...after `Log.w(..);`. it's really odd that IOException's message is null. i've never seen that. You could wrap the `Log.w()` code in a `try catch` block and get the NPE.

Comment: It's the only thing I could imagine causing a NullPointerException there, because `e` can't be null.  I decided on doing a null check and then `e.printStackTrace()` on the IOException if its message is null.  Thanks for the input.  Do you know why NullPointerException seems to print its stack trace without being explicitly told to sometimes, and other times (like this one) it doesn't?